# How to use MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonpath to do test?

Tags: mockito

I am writing some tests for spring mvc application.

I got the response as follows.

```
-> curl -X POST -H"Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8" localhost:8080/mvc/addBlacklist.do -d '{"id": "1", "imsi": "test"}'

{"id":0,"imsi":"18192729090","name":"xiaoshao","monitors":null}
```

But when my test like this one.

```
Blacklist blackList = new Blacklist();
    blackList.setId(0);
    blackList.setImsi("18192729090");
    blackList.setName("xiaoshao");

    when(blacklistService.add(any())).thenReturn(blackList);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/addBlacklist")
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(blackList))
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(status().is(200))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.imsi", is("xiaoshao")));
```

It emit an exception like this.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/InvalidPathException
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.<init>(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:53)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a dependency for the test. Add this to your maven pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I fixed the problem because of no dependency `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
```